# Proxmox migrated Windows10 Guest bluescreen while login

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I had a VMWare ESXI installation and I want to switch over to Proxmox. On the ESXI were running 2 Windows10 installations. So before switching over, I set up Proxmox in Virtualbox. Configured everything and it was ready to use. Then I followed [the official documention](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Migration_of_servers_to_Proxmox_VE) for migrating a VMWare host. My Windows10 is booting up, but as see I try to login. It comes to an bluescreen. "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you." And it restats as soon at it can.

My Virtualbox with Proxmox has 12GB RAM. 2 CPUs. Virtualization enabled. The Windows 10 Guest got also 2 CPUs and a range of 8 to 10GB RAM. While starting it uses little more than 8GB Ram (showing in Proxmox GUI). Someone know how to fix this? I completely followd the intructions step by step.

How well is the performance of a WINDOWS10 on Proxmox in comparison to VMWare? Running on same host with same setting?